# What is the Linux command to find out hardware info?

Tags: linux

I need to find out hardware information for the below items under Linux:

- CPU (and cores)
- CPU speed
- Memory
- Hard disks
- OS version

Any advice?

Comment: A nice GUI tool for this is [HardInfo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo).

Answer (score 99):

From [Linux Commands - A practical reference](http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html):

Show kernel version and system architecture

```
uname -a
```

Show name and version of distribution

```
head -n1 /etc/issue
```

Show all partitions registered on the system

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Show RAM total seen by the system

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
```

Show CPU(s) info

```
grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
```

Show info about disk sda

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 44):

Try `lshw`

It will suggest you run it as `root`, so try

```
sudo lshw
```

Comment: you will need to install it in many cases - iirc it wasn't stock in ubuntu

Comment: same issue on kali linux!

Answer (score 39):

Here is a list of commands to check hardware on Linux. Note that not all commands are available on all distributions. It is better to launch then as root (or via sudo) to get all the information.

**Command: lscpu**

- List available cpus and their caracteristics
- Not available on older distribution

**Command: lshal**

- Require HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) to be installed
- List all hardware visible by HAL

**Command: lshw**

- Available on Ubuntu based distributions by default, and Debian in the main repo
- Available in the Fedora repositories
- Uses many inputs to detect all hardware: Kernel, HAL, DMI, etc.
- As a neat ‘-html’ switch that generates hardware reports
- [Check more on this page](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/03/use-lshw-hardware-lister-to-get-detailed-information-on-the-hardware-configuration-of-your-linux-system/)

**Command: lspci**

- Standard command
- List all hardware connected to the PCI bus as detected by the kernel

**Command: lsusb**

- Standard command
- List all hardware connected to the USB buses as detected by the kernel

**Command: dmidecode**

- Standard command
- Get the source information from the DMI (a kind of BIOS interface)
- List all hardware as reported by the DMI interface

Answer (score 21):

I am a co-developer of a utility that is making its way into several distributions.  The tool is called [inxi](https://github.com/smxi/inxi).  It is a bash script that does what all the other answers here suggest in one easy command.  Check it out.

To use it, simply go to a terminal and type 'inxi -F' and it will display a full (-F) system information output.  'inxi -h' will show more options.  It was originally made for IRC troubleshooting, so it works in almost every IRC client (and comes bundled in some).

[image: inxi]

Comment: Though I don't develop on this tool any more.  I still highly recommend it.  I still use it.  The code was changed over to Perl at some point.  I don't know of many distros that don't have it in their repositories either.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a link to various Linux commands for what you want:

> http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-command-to-gathers-up-information-about-a-linux-system.html

Specifically, you're looking for commands like:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo

free -m

cat /proc/version
```

Answer (score 10):

And, just to add my two cents worth, I would also try

```
hwinfo
```

Before using the full comand, you might perhaps try the short version,

```
hwinfo --short
```

which might already provide the info you are searching for. The fll version is very rich in details, so it is probably best called with

```
hwinfo | more
```

And, by the way, a convenient condensed form of the info provided by lshw can be obtained by means of

```
sudo lshw -businfo
```

with easily readable output:

```
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
                              system         PORTEGE R930 (PT331E)
                              bus            PORTEGE R930
                              memory         128KiB BIOS
                              memory         6GiB System Memory
                              memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
                              memory         2GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
cpu@0                         processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
                              memory         32KiB L1 cache
                              memory         256KiB L2 cache
                              memory         4MiB L3 cache
                              memory         32KiB L1 cache
pci@0000:00:00.0              bridge         3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
pci@0000:00:02.0              display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
pci@0000:00:14.0              bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI     Host Controller
pci@0000:00:16.0              communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 
                                             MEI Controller #1
pci@0000:00:16.3              communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
pci@0000:00:19.0  eth0        network        82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:00:1a.0              bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
pci@0000:00:1b.0              multimedia     7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
pci@0000:00:1c.0              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
pci@0000:01:00.0              generic        MMC/SD Host Controller
pci@0000:00:1c.1              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
pci@0000:00:1c.2              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
pci@0000:04:00.0  wlan0       network        Centrino Advanced-N 6235
pci@0000:00:1c.5              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
pci@0000:00:1d.0              bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
pci@0000:00:1f.0              bridge         QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
pci@0000:00:1f.2              storage        7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
                 scsi0       storage        
scsi@0:0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           256GB TOSHIBA THNSNF25
scsi@0:0.0.0,1    /dev/sda1   volume         27GiB EXT4 volume
scsi@0:0.0.0,2    /dev/sda2   volume         210GiB Extended partition
                 /dev/sda5   volume         5722MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
                 /dev/sda6   volume         204GiB Linux filesystem partition
                 scsi2       storage        
scsi@2:0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD-RAM UJ8C2
                             power          Lithium Ion Battery
                          power          
                 wwan0       network        Ethernet interface
```

There is also a graphical version of lshw, called lshw-gtk:

```
sudo lshw-gtk &
```

Depeding on the specific distro you are on, most of these commands may need to be installed
(apt-get install, yum, pacman, ...)

Answer (score 2):

There is also popular non-standard script (requires installation) called [screenFetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch):

> screenFetch is a "Bash Screenshot Information Tool". This handy Bash script can be used to generate one of those nifty terminal theme information + ASCII distribution logos you see in everyone's screenshots nowadays. It will auto-detect your distribution and display an ASCII version of that distribution's logo and some valuable information to the right. There are options to specify no ASCII art, colors, taking a screenshot upon displaying info, and even customizing the screenshot command! This script is very easy to add to and can easily be extended.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want lots of information about all of the devices connected to your machine over the PCI (or PCI-Express) bus then type `lspci -vvknnqq`

If you want information about your disk partitioning then type `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *dmidecode* which will provide description of the systemâs hardware components.

Answer (score 1):

If you use puppet to manage your infrastructure, use [facter](http://puppetlabs.com/facter)

```
facter processorcount sp_number_processors sp_current_processor_speed memorytotal operatingsystem  osfamily operatingsystemrelease

processorcount => 4
sp_current_processor_speed => 2.5 GHz
sp_number_processors => 2
memorytotal => 8.00 GB
osfamily => RedHat
operatingsystem => CentOS
operatingsystemrelease => 6.5
```

You can even output as yaml or json

```
facter osfamily operatingsystem --json
{"osfamily":"Darwin","operatingsystem":"Darwin"}

facter osfamily operatingsystem --yaml
osfamily: Darwin
operatingsystem: Darwin
```

Chef has a similar tool called ohai

Answer (score 0):

The [hw-probe](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/) tool collects outputs of all hardware-related listers (hwinfo, lspci, lscpu, hdparm, smartctl, dmidecode, etc.) at once.